# Oracle REGEXP_LIKE Strange Behavior

Tags: oracle11g

Have a simple query it's failing for one set of parameters but it works for other parameters it's not working.

**This works:**

```
  SELECT R.*
FROM ROUTEUSER.AHC_B2B_ROUTE R
WHERE R.PRODUCER = 'Encounters'
AND REGEXP_LIKE ('tplmcoce.41.20170822.txt', R.FILEMASK, 'i')
```

**This is not working**

```
    SELECT R.*
FROM ROUTEUSER.AHC_B2B_ROUTE R
WHERE R.PRODUCER = 'Facets'
AND REGEXP_LIKE ('SMS-0162628062', R.FILEMASK, 'i')
```

If I have a column called Filemask (REGEX Pattern) in database so how can I select matching pattern for given string (file name)?

When I try the second query I am getting the following exception:

```
ORA-12725: unmatched parentheses in regular expression 12725. 00000 - "unmatched 
           parentheses in regular expression" 
*Cause: The regular expression did not have balanced parentheses. 
*Action: Ensure the parentheses are correctly balanced.
```

Comment: Without seeing the two patterns from `FILEMASK` how can we help you?

Comment: 1. "is not working" doesn't help anyone understand the issue. In what way is it not working? Does it throw an error? Does it produce the wrong result, or no result at all? We don't have your data, so there is no way for us to see that for ourselves. 2. "I have a column Filemask" is absolutely **not** something like **I give a string** - actually it is exactly the opposite. Do you give the string as a parameter at execution time, or do you (as in the code you posted) have a FILEMASK column, with possibly different values in each row of your table?

Comment: Here are the route masks ^tplmcoce[.](37|41|47|57)[.].*[.]txt$

Comment: Here are the route masks ^tplmcoce[.](37|41|47|57)[.].*[.]txt$ for other file ^SMS[-]0162628062$.

Comment: This query is    SELECT R.*
    FROM ROUTEUSER.AHC_B2B_ROUTE R
    WHERE R.PRODUCER = 'Facets'
    AND REGEXP_LIKE ('SMS-0162628062', R.FILEMASK, 'i') producing me results ORA-12725: unmatched parentheses in regular expression
12725. 00000 -  "unmatched parentheses in regular expression"
*Cause:    The regular expression did not have balanced parentheses.
*Action:   Ensure the parentheses are correctly balanced.

Comment: @mathguy thank you for your response. Yes I have regex stored in a table column and I am passing file name (string) as a argument to query to get the matching RegEx pattern. But I am getting the following exception, ORA-12725: unmatched parentheses in regular expression
12725. 00000 -  "unmatched parentheses in regular expression"
*Cause:    The regular expression did not have balanced parentheses.
*Action:   Ensure the parentheses are correctly balanced.

Comment: Ugh. That's nasty. The error message is pretty clear: one of the values in your FILEMASK column is incorrect, it has unbalanced parentheses. The issue is in the data; the code you wrote is correct. How many rows do you have where PRODUCER = 'Facets'? If it's not too many, you should be able to SELECT FILEMASK FROM (your table) WHERE PRODUCER = 'Facets' and inspect the regexp patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thought...

```
select *
from   <your_table>
where  regexp_count( FILEMASK, '\(' )  !=  regexp_count( FILEMASK, '\)' )
;
```

You should find at least one where PRODUCER = 'Facets' (and perhaps more?)

... although this may not be enough. Consider this regexp: `'\(abc)'` (where you meant `'\(abc\)'`). You want literal parentheses around the string `abc`. But you only escaped the opening parenthesis and forgot to escape the closing one. For a regular expression, that is an error: the escaped parenthesis is treated as any other character, it is not "special" in any way; this leaves the closing parenthesis as a special character, and it is not matched by an opening one.

On the other hand, my solution above is not able to distinguish between escaped and non-escaped parentheses - it treats them all the same, so `'\(abc)'` looks perfectly fine to it. If what I posted above is not enough, you/we will need more subtle ideas. Perhaps:

```
...
where regexp_count( FILEMASK, '([^\]|^)\(' )  !=  regexp_count( FILEMASK, '([^\]|^)\)'
```

This only looks for non-escaped parentheses. `[^\]` means "any character other than a backslash", and `([^\]|^)` means either that or the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT R.*
FROM ROUTEUSER.AHC_B2B_ROUTE R
WHERE R.PRODUCER = 'Facets'
AND REGEXP_LIKE ('^SMS[-]0162628062$*', R.FILEMASK, 'i') ---- Try and let us know output......................

Comment: What do you think the * does after $ in the regexp pattern? The downvote (one of them anyway) is from me; please don't post answers with such novice-level mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved. This is because I had one bad regular expression (missed one parenthesis) which caused the failure. The REGEX_LIKE started comparing each mask in table column when it come to the bad regex it failed.

Please close this question.

Thanks all.

Answer (score -1):

Escape the Chars in the `[]` with `'\'` . And you have to replace the last char `'.'` with `*` in the second pattern(`'SMS...'`)

```
^tplmcoce[\.](37|41|47|57)[\.].*[\.]txt$
and 
^SMS[\-]0162628062$*


SELECT 1 Matched
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('tplmcoce.41.20170822.txt',
                    '^tplmcoce[\.](37|41|47|57)[\.].*[\.]txt$', 'i');


SELECT 1 Matched
  FROM DUAL
 WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ('SMS-0162628062', '^SMS[\-]0162628062$*', 'i')
```

Comment: I don't think the [ and ] should be escaped; they are used correctly to enclose a character set. In the example it just happens that the character set has just one element, a dash, so the [ and ] are not needed; but escaping them makes no sense, really. Oh - and I just noticed (and it's a definite downvote now): What do you think the * does after $ in a regexp? It seems you don't know all that much about regexp.